# Entity Framework Vs Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-access-layer, shared-hosting

I want to know list of advantages of using Entity framework over data access layer.

My website is host in shared hosting and i don't have access to IIS

Considering that i am working shared hosting world, is it feasible to work with entity framework?

Comment: Entity framework **IS** data access layer

Comment: By Entity Framework I meant auto generated DAL, while data access layer (DAL) is manually created set of classes and method created on demand basis

Comment: It really isn't changing anything i stated above. Representation of DAL (ADO, L2SQL, EF, DataSet etc) doesn't really matter.

Comment: Do you mean Data Access Layer with ADO.NET/SqlHelper?

Comment: Could you please explain me little more by giving example.  I am new to this :( - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has publicly stated that Entity Framework will be the preffered data access technology for the .NET platform. Given your experience I feel like Entity Framework would be a huge asset to your ability to rapidly develop applications. Shared hosting is completely irrelevant to the fact that you are using entity framework. Just make sure that the hosting company supports .Net 4 framework (or w/e framework version you work with).

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is a data access layer.  Specifically it's an Object Relational Mapper.

So it basically comes down to - do you want to write your own DAL? - or would you rather spend your time building out the Data Model, and then having Entity create your entities and classes, etc.. for you.